# python func deletes previous pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have this function which works fine in calculating stuff I need, but the problem is, when I try to save it to a csv, is that it deletes all my previous calculated df... help please

```
dc = {'A':df['RSI']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dc)

print df

def func(row):
    if (row[['A']] > 70).all():
        return -1
    elif (row[['A']] < 30).all():
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


df['D'] = df.apply(func, axis = 1)
```

Comment: How do you save to the cvs? Probably you pass the argument `'w'` (write wife) instead of  `'a'` (append to file).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking to [append](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) in most programming languages "write" also truncates the file to zero length before writing anything.

Comment: yes, but df.append doesn't allow me to pass function as an argument. correct me here if I'm wrong I am not certain

Answer (score 0):

If you use `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv(your_arguments)` to write your file then the default mode parameter is 'w' that will overwrite the file with the new data. Try instead to use `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv(your_arguments, mode='a')` instead.

Using simply python is the same:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
```

will overwrite the file

```
with open(filename, 'a') as f:
```

will append new lines to the existing file.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I have managed to solve the problem using array like this:

```
field = []
field = pd.DataFrame(dc)
field = field.apply(func, axis = 1)
df['solution'] = pd.DataFrame(field)
```